# Vectorized sampling of multiple binomial random variables

Tags: python, numpy, random

I would like to sample a few hundred binomially distributed random variables, each with a different *n* and *p* (using the argument names as defined in the [numpy.random.binomial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) docs).  I'll be doing this repeatedly, so I'd like to vectorize the code if possible.  Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

# Made up parameters
N_random_variables = 500
n_vals = np.random.random_integers(100, 200, N_random_variables)
p_vals = np.random.random_sample(N_random_variables)

# Can this portion be vectorized?
results = np.empty(N_random_variables)
for i in xrange(N_random_variables):
    results[i] = np.random.binomial(n_vals[i], p_vals[i])
```

In the special case that *n* and *p* are the same for each random variable, I can do:

```
import numpy as np

# Made up parameters
N_random_variables = 500
n_val = 150
p_val = 0.5

# Vectorized code
results = np.random.binomial(n_val, p_val, N_random_variables)
```

Can this be generalized to the case when *n* and *p* take different values for each random variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,

```
import numpy as np

# Made up parameters
N_random_variables = 500
n_vals = np.random.random_integers(100, 200, N_random_variables)
p_vals = np.random.random_sample(N_random_variables)

# Can this portion be vectorized? Yes
results = np.empty(N_random_variables)
results = np.random.binomial(n_vals, p_vals)
```

Comment: Didn't even think to try this because *n* and *p* are specified as floats in the docs.  Does anyone know if this is a hidden feature that may get deprecated in the future, or just a case of missing documentation?

Comment: It was my understanding that it worked on `len(n)` & `len(p)` which are `int`. But then I have no backup for that claim.