# Efficient Numpy multiple sampling which results in a Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a 2d `numpy` matrix such that each row is a sampled draw from a bigger population (Without replacement).

I've created the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

full_population = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
number_of_iterations = 8
drawn_observations = 6
rng = np.random.default_rng()

for single_draw in range(number_of_iterations):
  indeces = rng.choice(a=full_population, size=drawn_observations, replace=False, shuffle=True)
```

However this code runs slowly (serially) comparing to my needs.

I've tried to look it up, this one seems close (But not exactly what i need) [vectorized question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062092/vectorized-sampling-of-multiple-binomial-random-variables/31062169)

Note that the real length of `full_population` is 2m , `number_of_iterations =  5000`, and `drawn_observations = 20k to 600k`

Any help on that would be awesome!

Comment: Do you collect `indeces` into a larger container? If not, you should be aware that any vectorized approach is going to have a larger memory footprint than needed.

Comment: @Charles Dupont thanks for the neat answer! notice my update on the real size of values, I'm worried that this type of solution wont hold.

Answer (score 1):

Use random permutations after repeatedly tiling your `full_population` array:

```
repeats = np.tile(full_population, (number_of_iterations, 1))
permutations = rng.permuted(repeats, axis=1)
sample_array = permutations[:, :drawn_observations]
```

Should be much faster than the looping approach!

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that this may have a very large temporary memory footprint, especially if the size of the population is much larger than the observations drawn.